# use compass function in scss

Tags: ruby, sass, compass

I have download all of the compass source,import it to scss,and compile with gulp(gulp-sass).however,I was having problems compile it.the gulp-sass through error：

```
Error: Undefined operation: "prefix-usage(browser-prefixes(browsers()), background-img-opts, (full-support: true), (partial-support: true)) gt 0.01".
    on line 324 of src/lib/_support.scss
```

After reviewing the official documentation, I found that the prefix-usage method is based on ruby and is compass-specific and not found in scss functions. This is my screenshot
[image]

I tried to find the source of this function in ruby, but unfortunately I did not find it.

Is there any solution that will allow me to migrate the compass project to gulp-sass as a whole?thanks for help.

Comment: The function is called prefix_usage: compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/cross_browser_support.rb:173:  def prefix_usage(prefix, capability, capability_options)